# Intellij Idea not reading files from standard input

Tags: java, algorithm, intellij-idea, intellij-14

So I was just starting out the Algorithms I course by Princeton University, wrote this code

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;

public class RandomWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        String winner = "";
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String cur = StdIn.readString();
            i++;
            if (StdRandom.bernoulli((double) 1 / i)) {
                winner = cur;
            }
        }
        StdOut.println(winner);
    }
}
```

This code works fine for me when I input strings through keyboard but for some reason for some reason nothing happens if I try to edit the Run -> program arguments and run it from animals8.txt.
I believe my code is corrent since

```
Test 2: check that the word the program prints appears on standard input
  * 10000 trials from coin.txt
  * 10000 trials from animals8.txt
  * 10000 trials from animals.txt
  * 10000 trials from colors.txt
  * 10000 trials from algorithms.txt
  * 10000 trials from dream.txt
==> passed

Test 3: check that program consumes all data from standard input
  * coin.txt
  * animals8.txt
  * animals.txt
  * colors.txt
  * algorithms.txt
  * names.txt
  * dream.txt
==> passed
```

The coursera autograder runs it just fine. Not sure what is going wrong here on my local intellij device

If anyone wants the Princeton library to test things out:
https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/hello/specification.php

Comment: https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/hello/specification.php

Comment: Your program reads from standard input. You can't provide input as command line parameters.

Comment: I thought the putting in files as the via the argument counts the same as typing the words in keyboard. What change should I do then? Also how the autograder is working inputting the files as standard input?

Comment: If you click on 'Modify Options' in the Intellij IDEA Run/Debug Configurations you can select 'Redirect Input' and choose a file to read from.